# Separate work & life accounts with a Macbook Pro M2 Pro possible?

Tags: dual-boot

I bought a MacBook Pro M2 Pro a few weeks ago.

I've been using my old MacBook Pro i5 8GB from 2012 for work (98% of my work is online: Zoom, Teams, Azure, Microsoft 365, Google WS, etc and web-based except for Zoom, Teams, and Outlook) but now I would like to use the new M2 for both work and personal stuff. (I could continue using my 2012 MacBook Pro, but it needs a new battery and I have to plug it in always, and I prefer to carry one laptop instead of two).

The main issue is that my employer requires that I install certain app to control the web pages/apps that I use (not complaining, just telling how it is). Since I don't want to log in to my personal stuff (iCloud, banks, social media, emails, photos, etc) while that app is running, I've created a new account.

But after installing the app, it appears in both my work and my personal accounts.

**Is there a way to have a really separate personal account so that when I log in to my work account, I cannot see and/or modify ANYTHING in my personal account and vice versa?**

I tried creating a new volume and installed macOS, but I need to access the files from one volume and vice versa!

Its driving me crazy!

Comment: So, this boils down to you have a Mac and you’d like to have two different users/profiles; one  for work and another for personal.  Your employer is making you use an App and you’d like to know how to keep it away from your person stuff, right?  Can you [edit] the question to focus on that aspect?  Include the name of the app and whether or not you or your employer owns this Mac.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1) The app your employer requires probably launches when starting up your Mac, that's why the app appears in both accounts. 2) Installing macOS on a different volume is the way to go, but then you write you need to access some files from the other volume, so it seems both accounts are not really separate at all. Can you clarify that?  Do you want two separate, independent accounts or should the personal account be able to access work files (or the other way around)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies.

I tried to separate the volumes.
I want to have my Personal volume totally separated from my work volume!

The thing is that because I'm an Admin in both volumes I can access the files from the other volumes vice versa
I dont want that! I want to have it like 2 different computers!

The app that I need to install into my work profile/volume requires an admin because it ask for Accessibility and record screen permissions.

So if I ran the app I need to set up those permissions with an Admin account.

Comment: I see... you could use FileVault to encrypt the contents of each volume, see https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/encrypt-mac-data-with-filevault-mh11785/mac, that would prevent that the "other" volume is mounted automatically. You will probably be prompted to enter a password to decrypt the "other" volume, but you can simply press cancel.